# How to draw a rounded rectangle with one side open (no connecting line on left side) using HTML canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to draw a rectangle (with three sides) which has rounded corners and no connecting line on the left hand side. For example, see below diagram (ignore imperfect hand drawing as the lengths are not drawn perfectly as parallel to each other):

[image]

This below example draws a full rectangle with rounded corners.

```js
// Now you can just call
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
// Draw using default border radius, 
// stroke it but no fill (function's default values)
roundRect(ctx, 5, 5, 50, 50);
// To change the color on the rectangle, just manipulate the context
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
roundRect(ctx, 100, 5, 100, 100, 20, true);
// Manipulate it again
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ddd";
// Different radii for each corner, others default to 0
roundRect(ctx, 300, 5, 200, 100, {
  tl: 50,
  br: 25
}, true);

/**
 * Draws a rounded rectangle using the current state of the canvas.
 * If you omit the last three params, it will draw a rectangle
 * outline with a 5 pixel border radius
 * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx
 * @param {Number} x The top left x coordinate
 * @param {Number} y The top left y coordinate
 * @param {Number} width The width of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} height The height of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} [radius = 5] The corner radius; It can also be an object 
 *                 to specify different radii for corners
 * @param {Number} [radius.tl = 0] Top left
 * @param {Number} [radius.tr = 0] Top right
 * @param {Number} [radius.br = 0] Bottom right
 * @param {Number} [radius.bl = 0] Bottom left
 * @param {Boolean} [fill = false] Whether to fill the rectangle.
 * @param {Boolean} [stroke = true] Whether to stroke the rectangle.
 */
function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {
  if (typeof stroke === 'undefined') {
    stroke = true;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'undefined') {
    radius = 5;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'number') {
    radius = {tl: radius, tr: radius, br: radius, bl: radius};
  } else {
    var defaultRadius = {tl: 0, tr: 0, br: 0, bl: 0};
    for (var side in defaultRadius) {
      radius[side] = radius[side] || defaultRadius[side];
    }
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius.tr, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius.tr);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius.br);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius.br, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius.bl);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius.tl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fill();
  }
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }

}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

So far I have tried below code by modifying the above one, but not able to draw it successfully. The
bottom part is getting messed up with fold in the bottom left corner and creating a diagonal which is not required at all.

```js
// Now you can just call
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
// Draw using default border radius, 
// stroke it but no fill (function's default values)
roundRect(ctx, 5, 5, 50, 50);
// To change the color on the rectangle, just manipulate the context
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
roundRect(ctx, 100, 5, 100, 100, 20, true);
// Manipulate it again
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ddd";
// Different radii for each corner, others default to 0
roundRect(ctx, 300, 5, 200, 100, {
  tl: 50,
  br: 25
}, true);

/**
 * Draws a rounded rectangle using the current state of the canvas.
 * If you omit the last three params, it will draw a rectangle
 * outline with a 5 pixel border radius
 * @param {CanvasRenderingContext2D} ctx
 * @param {Number} x The top left x coordinate
 * @param {Number} y The top left y coordinate
 * @param {Number} width The width of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} height The height of the rectangle
 * @param {Number} [radius = 5] The corner radius; It can also be an object 
 *                 to specify different radii for corners
 * @param {Number} [radius.tl = 0] Top left
 * @param {Number} [radius.tr = 0] Top right
 * @param {Number} [radius.br = 0] Bottom right
 * @param {Number} [radius.bl = 0] Bottom left
 * @param {Boolean} [fill = false] Whether to fill the rectangle.
 * @param {Boolean} [stroke = true] Whether to stroke the rectangle.
 */
function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {
  if (typeof stroke === 'undefined') {
    stroke = true;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'undefined') {
    radius = 5;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'number') {
    radius = {
      tl: radius,
      tr: radius,
      br: radius,
      bl: radius
    };
  } else {
    var defaultRadius = {
      tl: 0,
      tr: 0,
      br: 0,
      bl: 0
    };
    for (var side in defaultRadius) {
      radius[side] = radius[side] || defaultRadius[side];
    }
  }
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius.tr, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius.tr);
  //ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius.br);
  //ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius.br, y + height);
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius.bl);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius.bl, y + height + radius.tl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius.tl, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fill();
  }
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry but even if we remove the quadraticCurveTo on your code, your lines still are not making a rectangle, You have to break down each element you are drawing

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I have modified my answer to add an example which draws a rectangle , can u please help me modify it to get rid of the right side -- to make it having 3 sides (left, top & bottom)

Comment: removing a side can not be that difficult... just a process of elimination start commenting elements until you get the right result

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me as per my requirement :

```js
// Now you can just call
var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
// Draw using default border radius, 
// stroke it but no fill (function's default values)
roundRect(ctx, 5, 5, 50, 50);
// To change the color on the rectangle, just manipulate the context
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 0, .5)";
roundRect(ctx, 100, 5, 100, 100, 20, true);
// Manipulate it again
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ddd";
// Different radii for each corner, others default to 0
roundRect(ctx, 300, 5, 200, 100, {
  tl: 50,
  br: 25
}, true);


function roundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, fill, stroke) {
  if (typeof stroke === 'undefined') {
    stroke = true;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'undefined') {
    radius = 5;
  }
  if (typeof radius === 'number') {
    radius = {tl: radius, tr: radius, br: radius, bl: radius};
  } else {
    var defaultRadius = {tl: 0, tr: 0, br: 0, bl: 0};
    for (var side in defaultRadius) {
      radius[side] = radius[side] || defaultRadius[side];
    }
  }
  
  //  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl, y + height);
  //ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius.bl);
 
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x +width  , y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius.bl , y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y , x, y  + radius.bl);
  
  ctx.lineTo(x, y+ height -radius.bl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x , y + height , x + radius.bl , y + height );

  ctx.lineTo(x+width, y + height);
  //ctx.stroke();
  //ctx.closePath();
  

  if (fill) {
    ctx.fill();
  }
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
 

}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```